# Safe way to replace linux libs on embedded flash

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I have  a linux busybox based system on a chip.   I want to provide an update to users in the field and this requires updating some files in /lib /usr/bin and /etc.    I don't think that it's safe to simple untar the files directly.   Is there a safe way to do this including /lib files that may be in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things I strongly prefer in embedded systems:

a) Have the root file system be a ramdisk uncompressed from an image in flash.  This is great because you can experimentally monkey around with it to your heart's content and if you mess up, all you need is a reboot to get back to the flashed configuration.  When you have tested a set of change you like, you generate a new compressed root filesystem image and flash that.

b) Use a bootloader such as u-boot to do your updates - flashing a new complete image - rather than trying to change the linux system while it is running.  Though since the flashed copy isn't live, you can actually flash it while running.  If you flash a bad version, u-boot is still there to flash a good one.

c) Processors which have mask-rom UART (or even USB) bootloaders, making the system un-brickable - nothing more than a laptop and a serial cable or usb/serial converter is ever needed to do maintenance (ie, get a working u-boot image on the flash, which you then use to get a working linux kernel+compressed root fs image on it)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your flash device is big enough to partition into two complete filesystems and each update updates the *other* side (plus copying over config files if necessary) and updates the boot configuration to boot from the updated side.

Less ideal is to update in-place but have some means of detecting boot failure (watchdog that's not touched until after boot, for example) and have a smaller, fallback partition which is capable of accepting another update and fixing the primary partition.

As far as the in-place update of a live filesystem, just use a real installer (which will move the target files out of the way before replacing them to avoid the problem you describe).

Answer (score 0):

You received two excellent answers above and I Strongly encourage you to do what you were advised to.

There is, however, a more simple way. In a matter of fact you **can** just untar your libraries, provided that the process that does this is statically linked.